# Разделение данных для Машиного обучение

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня есть датафрэйм состоящий из 8640 строк и 11 столбцов. Первая строка состоит из 8 уникальных данных а второй столбец из 6 уникальных данных. Первый столбец [-7; 0] шаг 1, второй столбец [0; 10] шаг 2. И мне нужно разделить данные таким образом что бы для каждого элемента первого столбца, 2 элемента второго столбца в тестовый набор а 4 элемента второго столбца для тренировочного набора.

```
inputs_train, inputs_test, outputs_train, outputs_test = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 0)
```

Это не подходит поскольку мне не нужно рандомный деление. И я пробивал

```
 train_pct_index = int(0.833 * len(inputs))
 inputs_train, inputs_test = inputs[train_pct_index:], inputs[:train_pct_index]
 outputs_train, outputs_test =outputs[train_pct_index:], outputs[:train_pct_index]
```

Но здесь оно разделять всю дату на две части.

Comment: Ну так делайте выборку сами по вашим условиям. Которые я не совсем понял. Приведите конкретные примеры для вот этих "2 элемента, 4 элемента", как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: Вообще то ли стратификация то ли указание групп может помочь, но я так сразу не соображу. В `sklearn` есть оба варианта.

Comment: Я добавил фото в описание. В фото таблица до -2. но оно доходит до -7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, просто делаете условие на числа во второй колонке.

Для `Pandas DataFrame`:

```
test_filter = inputs['col2'] < 4
inputs_test = inputs.loc[test_filter]
inputs_train = inputs.loc[~test_filter]
```

Для `Numpy array`:

```
condition = arr[:,1] < 4
inputs_test = inputs[condition]
inputs_train = inputs[~condition]
```

По доп. вопросу из комментария:

```
condition = np.isin(arr[:,1], (4, 6))
```

Comment: А для нампай арр как будет?

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin Добавил

Comment: Спасибо большое работает!

Comment: А возможно ли сделать так что бы test set (4, 6), training set (0, 2, 8, 10)?

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin Добавил

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: В чем разница  `condition = np.isin(arr[:,1], (4, 6))` и `condition = np.isin(arr[:,1], (6, 4))` . Они же по сути одно и то же но на результат нейросети сильно влияет

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin Хм, не должно никак влиять, элементы, перечисляемые в кортеже, совершенно равноправны, их можно в любом порядке писать. Попробуйте список вместо кортежа для успокоения совести `[4,6]`, но разницы быть не должно.

Comment: теперь одинаково! но в чем причина если в скобках результат различается

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin А у вас в именно таких круглых скобках были значения?  Если бы фигурные скобки например `{4,6}`, то это будет множество и множество обрабатывается по-другому там. Но с кортежем `(4,6)` не должно быть никакой разницы :/